# CiviEvent: Public link for events of a specific type

Tags: civievent

Running CiviCRM 5.10.4 and Drupal 7.65.

We have several different event types in CiviEvent (e.g. PD Workshops, Volunteer Trainings, etc)

I'd like to be able to have a page on our website which automatically displays all the active events in specific event types. So then e.g. on our Volunteer page, rather than manually updating the page with the event links of upcoming  training dates, I could link to another page which lists all the upcoming events that have the event type "Volunteer Training".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a drupal view - You might need to enable the civicrm entity module.

You'll want to create a view that lists Civicrm Events then filter down the criteria you are using.

Comment: Indeed, I would do it as a view. You could have it as a page and link to it or even have it as a block. That block could then be placed in a sidebar, above or below your main content, etc just on that page. You can even insert the view into the body of your content. We do that all the time. You can see that right here where we have trainings for a specific state inserted into a page: https://www.tgci.com/funding-sources/california